# Evaluate the Integral with 2 Paths

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I'm guessing I will have to split this integral into 2. One with a circle and another one with a line. Then add them up.

How do I evaluate such a thing? What does this integral mean? Is the the length of the curve?

Answer (score 0):

The line integral can be thought of as the work done by the vector field $G(x,y)$ on a point particle along the path $C$. Consider the first part, it's simply along a linear function $x-1$ along $x\in[0,1].$

---

We parametrize the curve as,

$$y(t) = t-1$$
$$x(t) = t$$

with $0 \leq t \leq 1$. The line integral is,

$$\int G \cdot \, dr = \int G_x \, dx + G_y \, dy$$

Express $dx,dy$ in terms of dt:

$$dx = \frac{dx}{dt}dt = dt, \quad dy = \frac{dy}{dt} dt = dt$$

We find the line integral is,

$$\int_0^1 G_x(x(t),y(y)) + G_y(x(t),y(t)) \, dt = \int_0^1 \underbrace{t(t-1)}_{xy} + \underbrace{2(t-1)^2}_{2y^2} \, dt = \frac{1}{2}$$

Can you take it from here?